# What is a convex combination of graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, convex-optimization, trees, convex-geometry, planar-graphs

For example in [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1006.4586.pdf) paper, they refer to a "convex combination of trees" (pg. 2, first paragraph), and also, more generally, to "convex combination of graphs" (pg. 2, footnote).

-> "For instance, when K = V , the results of Racke [Rac08] give a convex combination of trees H with a loss of O(log n). We call this a tree-based flow-sparsifier, meaning that it is a convex combination of
trees."

-> "More generally, for a class F of graphs, we define an F-flow-sparsifier to be a sparsifier that uses a single graph from F, and an F-based flow-sparsifier to be a sparsifier that uses a convex combination of graphs from F."

Any examples, intuition/connection to the classical ideas of convexity would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should quote the paper instead of posting a link.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, added the quotes!

Answer (score 1):

It means a convex combination of characteristic vectors of graphs.  A characteristic vector is a $0$-$1$ valued vector, indexed by node pairs, in which a component of $1$ indicates that the corresponding edge is in the graph.

Comment: Could you suggest a reference? Does this definition apply only to graphs defined on the same set of vertices?

Comment: I don't have a reference, but yes vectors do need to have the same number of components to add them.